# blazor library that can do static JavaScript function

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Is here any blazor library that can do static JavaScript functions like add a class to an HTML tag something like this Instead of JS interop or something else just i don't want to use JavaScript i just want to add a class to an element

```
blazorFunctions.GetElementById("your element id").AddClass("your class name")
```

Comment: Maybe provide a little more context around what you are trying to do? There's zero need for JavaScript to dynamically add a class to a component in Blazor.

Comment: You can parameterize the class declaration in markup: `<div class="@ClassString" />`  Then change ClassString however you want in your C#.

Comment: Bennyboy1973 is there any other way? I asked it from ChatGPT, and it was trying to do it with element reference, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by parameterizing the class and use it in markup like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SetClassString">Set to class2</button>

<div class="@ClassString" />
    <p>Your content</p>
</div>

@code {

    public string ClassString { get; set; } = "class1";

    private void SetClassString()
    {
        ClassString = "class2";
    }
}
```

When used in a component you can also specifiy the `[Parameter]` attribute and pass in the class name from outside.

For example

```
<Index ClassString="class3" />
```